# Best practice for creating a mock object which will become part of another mock object

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a security model which has a `User` object. This `User` object has a 1 to many relationship with 2 different objects, a `Roles` object and a `Permissions` object - caveat being that a different `Role` and a different `Permission` can be referencing the same `User`. I'm writing a test (**not** necessarily a unit test) to test functionality around collections of `Roles` and `Permissions` as well as their methods but am unsure on how to create the `User` object which will be part the aforementioned objects.

Should I create some mockito'd `User` objects or create a real one under `@Before`? Is there a better method? Note that I'm new to mockito!

Comment: In this case it seems best to create 'real' objects under @Before, that objects would be more like stubs. That is because it seems that by using a mock you would have to set many expectations to these User objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `User`, `Roles`, and `Permissions` are all [*data* or *value objects*](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html): They don't really have interactions to test, but exist just to hold structured data. That makes it very compelling to use the real objects instead of painstakingly stubbing mocks: Why write `when(mockUser.getUserName()).thenReturn("bob")` when `User user = new User("bob")` works as well or better? This is especially true when you have setters: Mockito isn't very good for having getFoo() return X immediately after setFoo(X).

If so, it should be safe and easy to create real instances of all three of those objects, and associate them manually for your tests. You can probably extract a testing helper that creates and associates a predictable graph of User/Roles/Permissions.

If your model objects have methods like `archive`, `delete`, `sendEmail`, and so forth, the interactions become much more important and you may consider a [fake](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs) or a [selectively-stubbed partial mock](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy(T)). At that point, though, your model objects will probably come attached to a repository or service object, which may be more suitable for replacing in your tests.

Comment: In this specific test case I'm testing functionality after `when(service.getAllRoles()).thenReturn(.....)` and it is the calls inside the `.....` which require a `User` object.